# More concise way to filter a list?

Tags: python, filtering

If I have a list

```
a=[4, 5, 6]
```

as far as I know the simplest way to filter it is like:

```
[i for i in a if a<6]
```

Now I have just been introduced to dataframes, where for a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4, 5, 6], 'b':[7, 1, 2]})
```

I can apply a (row) filter just by specifying the element and the condition:

```
df[df['a']<6]
```

This seems more concise and maybe less confusing (once you get used to it) than the way to filter a list. Couldn't a list filter by applied by simply specifying a condition in the [], like

```
a[<6]
```

Obviously, it isn't implemented this way currently, but isn't the current method relatively verbose? Why couldn't it be simplified?

Comment: You can't do `a[<6]` with a dataframe either.

Answer (score 1):

You have the simplest way above. However, you can use the following

```
filtered_list = filter(lambda k: k < 6, original_list)
```

This looks great, but I still have a soft spot for the list comprehension.

Comment: Don't use a lambda in a situation like this, it is less efficient than the list comprehension.

Comment: I agree. List comp is the way forward. I just thought I give A.n.other method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have exactly the syntax you're asking for, but if you want to create your own list class, you can have one just as succinct:

```
class List(list):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return List(i for i in self if i < other)

a = List([4,5,6])
b = a < 6
assert b == [4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the python language could be built so that `a[<6]` did the filtering you want, but then every python programmer and every python compiler would have to learn that special syntax just to save a little source code in a few special cases: >, >=, ==, <=, <.

Pandas does something like that as you showed, but it is built for lots of numerical analysis, so that syntactic sugar may be more worth the cost. Also, pandas tends to provide lots of syntactic sugar inspired by the R language so it's not very idiomatic python.

Comment: As a complete novice to the intricacies of actually developing a programming language, please excuse me if I'm coming off as obnoxious or ignorant, but ....
couldn't whatever code handles slicing a list be written to interpret any conditional statement, including boolean combinations? It would seem like a fairly common and widespread application and not hard for programmers to learn a syntax which would be more straightforward and easier to learn than the current filtering idiom (though that does serve as a useful introduction to list comprehension).

Comment: It's always hard to get a syntax that compilers and humans both understand, without making it really complex. For example: why not `a[6>]` as shorthand for `[x for x in a if 6 > x]`? Then, everyone has to know where to put the `x`, but even pandas makes you put the dataframe[column] in its shorthand. Or, why not `a[+6]`? Given your rule, compilers would read that as `[x for x in a if x + 6]` (valid filter, btw), but, humans would probably read that as `[x + 6 for x in a]`. So, you'll need more complexity (read characters and/or bugs) to make it unambiguous and intuitive.

Comment: Thx @combinatorist.

Comment: Numpy arrays seem to make do with an even leaner expression of filters. (sorry for the delay, I'm a pythonista in training so you can tell where I'm up to in my coursework!).  Admittedly it's not a filter per se, but for an array A, A<0 produces a new boolean array and A+6 returns a new array with 6 added to each element.  It seems to work fine here, once you know how it works you know + is addition. So why not with list filtering?  I imagine dealing with all possible data types might be one reason ... (as opposed to arrays being restricted to numeric/boolean)?

Comment: Well, my last "excuse" is that python is a general language that is meant to serve in diverse domains whereas numpy is a very focused numerical / computational library. "Domain specific languages" like that tend to have more concise syntax because the context is obvious and the specialists using them don't want to type things again and again that are obvious in their context.

Comment: I hope it's obvious I'm not saying it's impossible, just that there are lots of trade offs to be considered in designing any language, but of course everybody's always looking to improve the languages they have to work with and that's why new ones get created so frequently.

Comment: yes I appreciate your comments and I can see that the more specific domains better lend themselves to specialised syntax that suits their type.  And in the case of lists I now realise the numpy syntax is effectively in place - there is a less than operator already for lists, it just means something different than what I wanted (a filter that returns all elements less than then specified expression...).  I guess if I think on it long enough I may think of conflicts/difficulties for list[<x] style syntax for filtering as well...